# C/C++ Static Library Current Directory

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

This is just a quick question. As I understand it, code from a static library is included directly, at compile time, into a .exe... so if I have some Library code running in a program, is it correct to say that the current directory as far as that code is concerned is the same as that of the .exe's, regardless of where the .lib is?

Comment: The current directory is a per-process setting that can change during execution (like when you do `cd` on the command-line). It is not necessarily the same as the directory where the exe resides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the lib is, even if it is dynamically linked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, correct. Current directory makes sense for the process. So, this is fair to say the same of loaded DLL's too

.lib is used as input for linker, resulting .exe does not use it

Answer (score 2):

Yes once your application is built with the library linked statically, you need not worry about where the lib is. All code is wrapped up inside the executable.